# How to tail/grep/awk the last N bytes of a file, rather than lines

Tags: cat, tail

I have an application that is logging to a plain text log file (myapp.log) but it doesn't seem to be writing new line characters at the end of each log entry. If I execute a command like `tail -n 50 myapp.log` I actually receive hundreds of "lines" of text (log entries).

This log file is very large, roughly 1GB, who knows how long ago the last CR and/or LF was inserterd. How can I just grab say, the last 2MBs for example?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using the `-c` switch (2MB = 2 * 1024 * 1024 = 2097152 bytes):

```
tail -c 2097152 myapp.log
```

---

Thanks to **Petr Uzel** for the suggestion. Some tail implementations allow to add a unit to print the last kilobytes (k) or megabytes (m), like:

```
tail -c 2m myapp.log
```

However please note that it is not standard (in none of POSIX, UNIX (SUS) or Linux (LSB)) and not portable. Also note that since the terms "Mega"/"kilo"... and their abbreviations (M, k...) have ambiguous meanings (1000 vs 1024), there's not much guarantee of what this or that implementation of `tail` will mean by `2m` (though the current versions of the current implementations that do support it seem to be going for the 1024 variant).

Comment: Tail should be able to accept number with units as argument for the c switch, so `tail -c 2M myapp.log` should also work.

Comment: @PetrUzel: Thanks. Edited the answer to add it.

Comment: Now I feel silly :) Thanks for the promptness, really appreciate that. Great suggestion!

Comment: Perfect, Not sure if this will help but i'll add this text-string because it's what i was the keywords i was searching for to get here (took a good while): **"cat file data between two byte positions (not lines)"**

Comment: If you're using MacOS, you need to use Homebrew and then `gtail` in order not use the awful version Apple have decided to provide (which took several minutes before I gave up executing `tail -c 2000 mybigfile` whereas `gtail -c 2k mybigfile` took virtually no time at all)